# Building android source

Tags: android, makefile, smartcard, android-source, android-build

I am to build an Android image from source but with smart card api support.

I have listed the steps that I had done and errors that I face.

```
Patching Smart card API with android source

1. Downloaded android source “android-2.3.5_r1” from the “source.android.com”
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH
$ mkdir ANDROID2.3.5_r1
$ cd ANDROID2.3.5_r1
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.5_r1
$ repo sync

The download was successful and complete

2. Downloaded the Smart card patch “smartcard-api-2_3_0.tgz” from “code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/downloads”

3. Applying the patches
$ cd <ANDROID_ROOT_DIR>
$ patch -p1 < <path_to_my_patches>/smartcard-api-2_3_0/smartcard-api.patch
$ patch -p1 < <path_to_my_patches>/smartcard-api-2_3_0/uicc.patch
$ patch -p1 < <path_to_my_patches>/smartcard-api-2_3_0/emulator.patch
$ patch -p1 < <path_to_my_patches>/smartcard-api-2_3_0/cts.patch
$ make update-api

All the patches were successfully applied with no errors and hunk failures

4. Building the Source
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch full-eng
$ make -j2
```

The error that appeared is as follows

```
target thumb C: SRecTestAudio <= external/srec/srec/test/SRecTestAudio/src/SRecTestAudio.c
system/media/opensles/tests/automated/BufferQueue_test.cpp:34:29: error: SLES/OpenSLESUT.h: No such file or directory
system/media/opensles/tests/automated/BufferQueue_test.cpp: In function 'void CheckErr(SLresult)':
system/media/opensles/tests/automated/BufferQueue_test.cpp:55: error: 'slesutResultToString' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/BufferQueue_test_intermediates/BufferQueue_test.o] Error 1
```

Comment: i'll not downvote this, but it not belongs here try http://android.stackexchange.com/ or maybe xda forum anddroid tag says `Android is Google's software stack for mobile devices. Please use the Android-specific tags such as [android-intent], not [intent]. For non-developer questions, see http://android.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Sorry selvin. I would be of nice help if u find articles related to this and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error and followed [this](http://wyk525.iteye.com/blog/1224199) link which solved the problem.

I will explain what it says,

- cd to your aosp directory

  ```
  cd /path/to/ur/aosp
  ```
- Open file system/media/opensles/tests/automated/BufferQueue_test.cpp  using any editor for example.

  ```
  vi system/media/opensles/tests/automated/BufferQueue_test.cpp
  ```
- now add the include files that are described in the link and save the file BufferQueue_test.cpp
- now use these commands

  ```
  sudo updatedb

  locate OpenSLESUT.h /home/ur aosp path/system/media/opensles/libopensles/OpenSLESUT.h 

  cp /home/ur aosp path/system/media/opensles/libopensles/OpenSLESUT.h /home/<ur aosp path>/system/media/opensles/include/SLES/OpenSLESUT.h
  ```

**NOTE** : your aosp path is the path to your aosp android project.